# line to point collision without doing three square roots

Tags: collision-detection

Is it possible to test a point to line collision without doing three square roots? Here's how I'm currently doing it:

I have point P that I want to check is on the line, and point A and B for the two ends of the line. I use the Pythagorean equation to get length PA, PB, and AB. Now I check to see if PA + PB = AB. if PA + PB is larger than AB, the point cannot be on the line.

```
private boolean PTLCollisionCheck(float px, float py, float ax, float ay, float bx, float by) {
    float PA = (float) Math.sqrt(((px - ax) * (px - ax)) + ((py - ay) * (py - ay)));
    float PB = (float) Math.sqrt(((px - bx) * (px - bx)) + ((py - by) * (py - by)));
    float lineLength = (float) Math.sqrt(((ax - bx) * (ax - bx)) + ((ay - by) * (ay - by)));
    return (PA + PB) <= (lineLength + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In 2D, we can use a trick that if we exchange the x & y of a vector and negate one of them, we get a vector perpendicular to the one we started with very cheaply.

```
Vector2 span = pointB - pointA;

Vector2 perpendicular = new Vector2(-span.y, span.x);

Vector2 offset = pointP - pointA;

float perpendicularDot = Vector2.Dot(offset, perpendicular);
```

This dot product (`offset.x*perpendicular.x + offset.y*perpendicular.y`) is proportional to how far our point strays off the line - positive for the half plane "above" the line, negative for the half plane "below", and zero when our point sits exactly on the line. Specifically, it's our distance off the line times the length of the line segment itself.

Due to precision limits, our point will almost never fall exactly on the line, so you'll often want to check when this value changes signs (meaning it crossed the line somewhere between the last check and this one), rather than waiting for it to hit zero perfectly.

You can also use an epsilon to say "values in this range are close enough to zero to count", similar to the `+1` fudge factor in your current algorithm - but you'll want to adjust for the length of the line segment if using lengths over different orders of magnitude. Or you can store a unit normal for each segment to get a true perpendicular distance cheaply.

Once we know our point is somewhere on the (infinite) line, we need to check whether it's between the endpoints of our segment. We can do that with another dot product:

```
float spanDot = Vector2.Dot(span, offset);

// If negative, we're behind the start point.
if (spawDot < 0f) 
   return false;

// If greater than the squared magnitude of span, we're past the end point.
if (spanDot > Vector2.Dot(span, span))
   return false;

return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are many solutions, but this is the first one I thought of. It's fairly simple and only involves basic algebra (which based on the method you proposed I assume you understand), but I'm going to go through it fully to try and ensure it makes sense:

First, ensure that px is between the values of ax and bx, and that py is between ay and by. If either is false, then it is impossible for the point to be on the line segment. The way I did this in the code example below was to check if either **ax <= px <= bx** or **bx <= px <= ax** were true (because it is unknown whether or not ax or bx is greater, doing it this way ensures that the check is *true* in either case). The check for py is done the same way. If either px or py were not between, *false* is automatically returned because the point cannot be on the line segment AB. For readability, another function called *IsBetween* was made for this check.

Now begins the algebra.

All lines can be modeled using a linear equation. In this case, I'd use the form

**f(x) = y = m(x - x1) + y1**,

where m is the slope of the line and x1, y1 represent any coordinate pair on the line

The slope can be calculated fairly easily using the slope formula ((by - ay) / (bx - ax)), and the point (x1, y1) can be either the start or end point (since both are, of course, on the line)

If point (px, py) is on line AB, then this equation *must* be true when (px, py) is plugged into it.

If **f(px) = py**, then the point (px, py) is on the line AB. Otherwise, it is not. Because we already checked to ensure that px was between ax and bx and that py was between ay and by, if this is true, then (px, py) is on the line segment AB, meaning we can have *PTLCollisionCheck* return *true*.

Here is a code example I made (because you did not specify a specific language I wrote it in C#, although it is a simple enough function that only minor changes should need to be made for it to work in other languages):

```
private bool PTLCollisionCheck(float px, float py, float ax, float ay, float bx, float by)
{
     if (!(IsBetween(px, ax, bx) && IsBetween(py, ay, by)))
     {
          return false;
     }

     float slope = (by - ay) / (bx - ax);

     return (slope * (px - ax) + ay == py);
}

private bool IsBetween(float testNum, float a, float b)
{
     return (a <= testNum <= b) || (b <= testNum <= a);
}
```